Deleting images and tables that aren't under an specific Heading with python-docx
I have to change a lot of docx documents. I need to strip some content and only leave the relevant one.
All docx files have the same structure, I need to keep text, images and tables under certain headings. I'm trying to use the library python-docx.
I'm writing an script that deletes all text that isn't under those Headings, but I'm having a hard time deleting images and tables.
So far my code looks like this:

from docx import Document

def delete_paragraph(paragraph):
    p = paragraph._element
    p.getparent().remove(p)
    p._p = p._element = None
    
def clean_doc(path_in: Path, path_out: Path, headings: list):
    doc = Document(path_in)
    keep_para = False
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        if para.text in headings and para.style.name == 'Heading 3':
            keep_para = True
        elif para.style.name != 'Normal' and para.text not in headings:
            keep_para = False
        if not keep_para:
            delete_paragraph(para)
    doc.save(path_out)

headings = ['FIRST TITLE', 'THIRD TITLE', 'APPENDIX']
path_in = Path('path/to/file.docx')
path_out = Path('path/to/file2.docx')

clean_doc(path_in, path_out, headings)

It removes all text content that is not under the desired headings, but I haven't found a way to remove pictures and tables outside of the headings. I've been reading the python-docx documentation and I'm afraid maybe is not possible to do what I want.
I'm using Python 3.12 in WSL (Windows 11, Ubuntu). I have access to Linux Machines running Ubuntu and Fedora.
¿Any way to achieve what I want, with python-docx, other python library or any other software?
Thank you.
